# XML Serialisation: what happens when an object reference is added?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I started with the following code:

```
public class ChangeRestartProcessing
{
    [XmlElement("ID")]
    public long TransportId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("FI")]
    public Information FinalInformation { get; set; }
}
```

... and while serialising, everything worked fine: `FI` was visible in the XML serialisation result.

Now, I've made following modification:

```
public class ChangeRestartProcessing
{
    [XmlElement("ID")]
    public long TransportId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("FI")]
    public Information FinalInformation { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("DI")]
    public Information NormalInformation { get; set; }
}
```

The idea is to see the `FI` when that object exists, and to see `DI` when that object exists (it never happens that both are present).

However, now I don't see any `FI` or `DI` tag in my XML serialisation  result.

Is that normal and what can I do in order to make the mentioned tags visible? Do I need to create a separate class for both cases or is there another approach?

Comment: works fine here; if I add a `NormalInformation`, I get `<DI>`; if I add a `FinalInformation` I get a `<FI>`. Can you show code that doesn't work as you expect?

Comment: running example: https://sharplab.io/#v2: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

Comment: The idea is to get `<DI>` and no `<FI>` in case of `NormalInformation`, and no `<DI>` but `<FI>` in case of `FinalInformation`, is that what you get?

Comment: yes, it works exactly like that; can you show runnable code that *doesn't* work like this?

Comment: @MarcGravell: Also thanks for that C# simulator, that might be very useful in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine here...

```cs
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ChangeRestartProcessing));
serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, // has ID+FI only
    new ChangeRestartProcessing
    {
        FinalInformation = new() { Id = 42 },
    });
Console.WriteLine();
serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, // has ID+DI only
    new ChangeRestartProcessing
    {
        NormalInformation = new() { Id = 42 },
    });

public class ChangeRestartProcessing
{
    [XmlElement("ID")]
    public long TransportId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("FI")]
    public Information FinalInformation { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("DI")]
    public Information NormalInformation { get; set; }
}
public class Information
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Codepage - 850"?>
<ChangeRestartProcessing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ID>0</ID>
  <FI Id="42" />
</ChangeRestartProcessing>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Codepage - 850"?>
<ChangeRestartProcessing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ID>0</ID>
  <DI Id="42" />
</ChangeRestartProcessing>
```

Comment: Youre right, I'm sorry. The issue was caused by a missing attribute.